# Why adding association mark my model as not valid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, tdd, minitest

I'm developing a simple weather API in Rails. This API will give the forecast for a given day. The forecast will have hourly data about the wind, temperature, relative humidity, etc.

I have implemented a model for the Forecast. The forecast have an association "has_many" with the other models, for example, the Wind. I have developed the following model for the Wind object:

```
class Wind < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :forecast, foreign_key: true
  validates_presence_of :period
  validates :velocity, numericality: true, allow_blank: true
  validates :direction, length: { maximum: 2 }, allow_blank: true
end
```

As I am trying to use TDD, I have implemented the following tests (among others):

```
class WindTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  setup do
    @valid_wind = create_valid_wind
    @not_valid_wind = create_not_valid_wind
  end

  test 'valid_wind is valid' do
    assert @valid_wind.valid?
  end

  test 'valid_wind can be persisted' do
    assert @valid_wind.save
    assert @valid_wind.persisted?
  end

  test 'not_valid_wind is not valid' do
    assert_not @not_valid_wind.valid?
  end

  test 'not valid wind cannot be persisted' do
    assert_not @not_valid_wind.save
    assert_not @not_valid_wind.persisted?
  end

  test 'not_valid_wind has error messages for period' do
    assert_not @not_valid_wind.save
    assert_not @not_valid_wind.errors.messages[:period].empty?
  end

  test 'not_valid_wind has error messages for velocity' do
    assert_not @not_valid_wind.save
    assert_not @not_valid_wind.errors.messages[:velocity].empty?
  end

  test 'not_valid_wind has error messages for direction' do
    assert_not @not_valid_wind.save
    assert_not @not_valid_wind.errors.messages[:direction].empty?
  end

  private

  def create_valid_wind
    valid_wind = Wind.new
    valid_wind.direction = 'NO'
    valid_wind.velocity = 2
    valid_wind.period = '00-06'
    valid_wind.forecast_id = forecasts(:one).id
    valid_wind
  end

  def create_not_valid_wind
    not_valid_wind = Wind.new
    not_valid_wind.velocity = 'testNumber'
    not_valid_wind.direction = '123'
    not_valid_wind
  end
end
```

This bunch of tests was passing before I add the association with forecast:

```
belongs_to :forecast, foreign_key: true
```

Indeed, if I remove that line, any test fails. But with that line in the model, the following tests are failing (they are false and the test expects true):

```
  test 'valid_wind is valid' do
    assert @valid_wind.valid?
  end

  test 'valid_wind can be persisted' do
    assert @valid_wind.save
    assert @valid_wind.persisted?
  end
```

I am trying to understand why this is happening. Anyone knows why those tests are failing? Also, is there any proper way to test associations?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What if you just use `belongs_to :forecast`?

Comment: To test associations, you can use fixtures. Try this [tutorial](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/how-to-test-rails-models-with-minitest`).

Comment: @DiodonHystrix If I remove the foreign_key: true, the tests are working. Why is this happening? It is correct to remove foreign_key: true? And thanks for the association test tutorial :)

Comment: `true` is not a valid value for the `foreign_key` option, `foreign_key` is where you specify the name of the foreign key column if it's different than the default (the default in this case being `forecast_id`).

Comment: For more information about `belongs_to` options, check [it](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to). Look at the examples to better understand it :)

Comment: Thank you so much @philomory. I usually read the guides, my fault. Sorry for my late answer.

Comment: Thank you so much @DiodonHystrix. The tests are now working. Sorry for my late answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test 'valid_wind can be persisted' do
  assert @valid_wind.save
  assert @valid_wind.persisted?
end
```

This test is close to worthless since you are only testing that the test setup is correct, it tells you nothing about the application under test.

Instead in your model tests you should test on a per validation basis:

```
test 'does not allow non numerical values for velocity' do
  wind = Wind.new(velocity: 'foo')
  wind.valid?
  assert_match "is not a number", wind.errors.full_messages_for(:velocity)
end

test 'allows numerical values for velocity' do
  wind = Wind.new(velocity: 3)
  wind.valid?
  refute(wind.errors.include?(:velocity))
end
```

Testing passing values is usually just marginally useful but can be valuable if bugs occur.

In your models you don't really need to worry about setting up completely valid records - your functional and integration tests will cover that anyways.

Comment: On a side not I think you may have really missed the mark with your domain modeling. Splitting the fields of a typical weather forecast into multiple tables just ups the complexity and will lead to performance problems. I think what you need in the first place is to model it as multiple forecasts per day. Not one forecast per day with a bunch of different chunks.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I am relatively new to Rails. And yes, you are right, I can simplify more my models. I need to think more about them.